# scala play json custom validation oneOf

Tags: json, scala, validation, playback

How to validate json where-in one of 2 keys is mandatory.

Ex1: valid Json

```
{
    "userName": "MyName",
    "userId": 123
}
```

Ex2: valid Json

```
{
    "userName": "MyName"
}
```

Ex3: valid Json

```
{
    "userId": 123
}
```

Ex4: InValid Json - Missing both UserName and userId

```
{
    "email": "email@email.com"
}
```

My case class is below

```
case class FindUser(userName: Option[String], userId: Option[Int]
object FindUser {
  implicit val findUserReads = Json.reads[FindUser]
}
```

Controller:

```
request.body.validate[FindUser]
```

Comment: with which JSON library?

Comment: I’m using play-json library

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As one of the solutions, you could implement your own `def reads(json: JsValue): JsResult[A]`:

```
import play.api.libs.json._

case class FindUser(userName: Option[String], userId: Option[Int])

object FindUser {
  implicit val findUserReads: Reads[FindUser] = new Reads[FindUser] {
    override def reads(json: JsValue): JsResult[FindUser] = {
      // Read and validate `userName` node
      val nameJsRes: JsResult[Option[String]] = (json \ "userName").validateOpt[String]
      // Read and validate `userId`
      val idJsRes: JsResult[Option[Int]] = (json \ "userId").validateOpt[Int]

      // For-comprehension which will fail fast
      // It will give JsError if:
      //  - nameJsRes is invalid
      //  - idJsRes is invalid
      //  - name and is are empty
      for {
        name <- nameJsRes
        id <- idJsRes
        result <- if (name.isEmpty && id.isEmpty) {
          JsError(JsonValidationError("Either `userName` or `userId` must be set"))
        }
        else {
          JsSuccess(FindUser(name, id))
        }
      } yield result
    }
  }

  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    // JsSuccess(FindUser(Some(123),Some(1123)),)
    println(Json.parse(
      """{
        |    "userName": "123",
        |    "userId": 1123
        |}""".stripMargin).validate[FindUser])

    // JsSuccess(FindUser(None,Some(1123)),)
    println(Json.parse(
      """{
        |    "userNameXXX": "123",
        |    "userId": 1123
        |}""".stripMargin).validate[FindUser])

    // JsSuccess(FindUser(Some(123),None),)
    println(Json.parse(
      """{
        |    "userName": "123",
        |    "userIdXXX": 1123
        |}""".stripMargin).validate[FindUser])

    // JsError(List((,List(JsonValidationError(List(Either `userName` or `userId` must be set),WrappedArray())))))
    println(Json.parse(
      """{
        |    "userNameXXX": "123",
        |    "userIdXXX": 1123
        |}""".stripMargin).validate[FindUser])
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you. This works for me. I could get rid of additional custom code I was writing to do the same.